# Calculus midterm exam help.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I received my grade for my calculus midterm and according to my professor I answered the two following questions incorrectly but he refuses to tell me why. If anyone could explain to me where I went wrong I would appreciate it greatly.

[image: First question I got wrong]

[image: My solution to the first question]

[image: Second question I got wrong]

[image: My solution to the second question]

According to my professor, the proof used in the first question is insufficient. For the second question, he claims my answer is incorrect and should be (3cos(t), 3sin(t), t).

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: For the second problem, $\cos{0}=1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: For the first problem, perhaps he disagrees with you on what the "equation of the plane" is supposed to be. For instance: you might have had to write it as the single equation $ax+by+cz-d=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**For question 1**

I imagine that your professor was expecting you to provide a cartesian equation of the plane in the form $ax + by +cz = 0$. So you should expand what you wrote with $ \vec r = x \vec i + y \vec j +z \vec k$.

**For question 2**

Your initial speed is incorrect and equal to $6 \vec j$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I now see what I did wrong with question 2. For the first question, he didn't have a problem with my equation for the plane but with the proof.

Comment: I don't understand why he has an issue with the proof. Maybe he would have like you to notice that $\vec{P_1 P2} \times \vec{P_1 P_3} \neq \vec 0$???

Comment: Hmm, I'm not exactly sure. This is a direct quote after I inquired about the question: "For number 2, you need to show that they are on the same plane. You wrote down the equation using the formula you provided, but that's not the same as showing they are on the same plane." That's all he's told me so far and has ignored my requests to go into more detail.